# Parsing a string and putting the index of the token into a table

Tags: c, parsing, search

I wrote code to find the start and end of a (single or double) quotation mark, a series of characters, or a "|" and then putting those values into an array. For some reason I keep getting segfault.  Also, afterwards, how do I display the table to see if it is working?

```
   int parsing(const char *commandline, int array[])
{
    int number= 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(commandline[index]!= '\0'){

        /* when you have spaces*/
        if (isspace(commandline[index]))
            index++;

        /* when you have double quotes*/
        if(commandline[index] == '"'){
            printf("running");
            array[number] = index;
            number++;
            index++;
            while(commandline[index] != '"' || '\0')
                index++;
            if(commandline[index] == '\0')
                return printf("ERROR: Quote not ended");
            array[number]= index;
            number++;
        }

        /* when you have single quotes*/
        if(commandline[index] == '\''){
            array[number] = index;
            number++;
            index++;
            while(commandline[index] != '\'' || '\0')
                index++;
            if(commandline[index] == '\0')
                return printf("ERROR: Quote not ended");
            array[number]= index;
            number++;
        }


        /* when you have |*/
        if ( commandline[index] == '|')
        {
            array[number] = index;
            number++;
        }


        /* when you have only letters*/
        if(isalnum(commandline[index])){
            array[number] = index;
            index++;
            number++;
            while (isalnum(commandline[index]))
                index++;
            array[number] = index;
        }

    }


  return *array;
}
```

EDIT: ADDED ERROR CHECKING

Comment: What if the last character is a space? Or the second of `'"'`? Or if the string doesn't *have* a second `'"'`?

Comment: I haven't done that yet, I'm trying to see if just this much works

Comment: Use gdb to check the line of the segfault. And to display your array, use a simple for loop and display each entry with a printf.

Comment: I got the printing to work as well. My only problem is the single and double quotes. I get a set fault when I try to put single or double quotes

Comment: Some of those problems probably was the reason you got the crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found multiple things to improve, added them as comments:

```
int parsing(const char *commandline, int array[])
{
    int number= 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(commandline[index]!= '\0'){

        /* when you have spaces*/
        if (isspace(commandline[index])) {
            index++;
            continue;  // So that if you are at the end of the string 
                       // you don't segfault.
       }

        /* when you have double quotes*/
        if(commandline[index] == '"'){
            printf("running");
            array[number] = index;
            number++;
            index++;
            // || '\0' just does nothing. Do:
            while(commandline[index] != '"') {
                if(commandline[index] == '\0') {
                    // returning printf sounds  silly. printf returns the number
                    // of character written.
                    // Also: Add \n to your printf.
                    printf("ERROR: Quote not ended\n");
                    return -1;
                }
                index++;
            }
            array[number]= index;
            number++;
            index++;
            continue;  // Same as for when you have spaces.
        }

        /* when you have single quotes*/
        if(commandline[index] == '\''){
            array[number] = index;
            number++;
            index++;
            // Ditto there.
            while(commandline[index] != '\'') {
              if(commandline[index] == '\0') {
                printf("ERROR: Quote not ended\n");
                return -1;
              }
              index++;
            }
            array[number]= index;
            number++;
            index++;
            continue;  // here also.
        }

        /* when you have |*/
        if ( commandline[index] == '|')
        {
            array[number] = index;
            number++;
            index++;  // move to next character.
            continue;
        }


        /* when you have only letters*/
        if(isalnum(commandline[index])){
            array[number] = index;
            index++;
            number++;
            while (isalnum(commandline[index]))
                index++;
            array[number] = index;
            continue;
        }
        // And if you get here, you have neigher an alphanum nor a | nor a "
        // nor a ', what do you want to do ?
        index++;
        continue;

    }


  return *array;
}
```

Comment: this is great. Got rid of the set fault. I did add the continues. Now my only problem is getting the correct indices

Comment: Add some printf in your code to 'see' what it is doing. gdb is also an option but it's often more difficult to use than just printfs ;)

Comment: For some reason it says quote not ended if you try to run the code with single or double quotes

Comment: Got it ! You need an index++ in these cases (before the continue) or index points to the ending quote and the main loop starts again.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out as well. Thank you so mucchhh!